# Are there Cocktail bars in London that can be booked < 4 weeks in advance?

Tags: food-and-drink, london, nightlife

I will be in London for a theatre trip on a Saturday in September and would like to visit a rooftop bar before the theatre for a drink/cocktail.

Having looked at web sites for many of these bars, they would appear to be fully booked. Are there bars that I might be able to book for 4 weeks time?

Comment: By 'theatre' we're talking Covent Garden/West End?  Also, do you want a table? Or place at the bar?

Comment: I was able to get a table in The Shard during the busiest tourist season without issues (on a Friday night!). I wouldn't worry about reservations.

Comment: Did you just look at websites or did you try to contact them calling or sending an email (better to call I guess). Reservation websites are not as much of a thing in Europe AFAIK. Also the interfaces you stumbled upon where for booking a spot for one person or the whole places?